# Parsing Text And Two Variables, PHP

Tags: php, string, variables

I have a question on parsing this line of php code. I've tried but cant get it, I have also searched tons of forums but could not find the right thing. Could someone help?

```
$message = "CheckSMS= . $_POST['number'] . "=" . $_POST['message'];
```

In the end it should look like this: CheckSMS=number=message

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and im trying to make it look like this: CheckSMS=1234=hi

Comment: then make it `$message = "CheckSMS=" . $_POST['number'] . "=" . $_POST['message'];`

Comment: Thank you Lashane! I guess I originally forgot the " after sms.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax highlighting shows your errors, you're missing the closing `"` on the first one.

```
$message = "CheckSMS= . $_POST['number'] . "=" . $_POST['message'];
```

Should be:

```
$message = "CheckSMS=" . $_POST['number'] . "=" . $_POST['message'];
```

You should probably also do some input validation and so on, because you can't fully ever trust a POST variable, etc, but this solves this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There's several ways to do this:

```
// Complex (curly) syntax
$message = "CheckSMS={$_POST['number']}={$_POST['message']}";

// Concatenation
$message = "CheckSMS=".$_POST['number']."=".$_POST['message'];

// sprintf()
$message = sprintf("CheckSMS=%s=%s", $_POST['number'], $_POST['message']);
```

Comment: good candidate for heredoc also